# Finding ruby on rails records from 'has many through' join table, is there an easier way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 'has many through' relationship between two Models:

```
Task:  
has_many :placements
has_many :games, :through => :placements

Game:
  has_many :placements
  has_many :tasks, :through => :placements

Placements:
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :game
```

In my controller's index method I want to list only those tasks that have a particular game id.
The solution I came up with uses an array of id's, but I am thinking there must be an easier, however less obvious to me, way of doing this!

@tasks = Task.find(Placement.where(:game_id => current_user.selectedgame).collect(&:task_id))

Any suggestions most welcome please.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but...

```
@tasks = Game.find(current_user.selectedgame).tasks
```

You probably should use `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: Thanks very much! I was sure there was an easier way.

Comment: Thanks, using hasmanythrough so i can have extra fields in the join.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the `Games` object:

```
Games.find(current_user.selectedgame).tasks
```

You can use `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships instead of `has_many :through`, but it's not necessary.  The [Ruby on Rails Guide about Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) has [a section about this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many).